# How to "bring along another variable" with dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, max, summarize

I want to get the maximum value in each combination of conditions, but also bring along the value of another variable of the same index.

```
df <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear,carb) %>%
  summarise(max_cyl = max(cyl))
```

But what do I do to "bring along" the corresponding mpg for each car with its maximum? This seems like a basic thing, but it also appears to be absent from the dplyr tutorials.

In other words, I want to select only those cars with the maximum number of cylinders in each gear x carb condition, and know the gas mileage for that same car.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "bring along"? `summarize` will reduce data dimensionality from a vector of `wt` values to a single scalar `max_cyl`. How do you want to capture the vector of `mpg` values in this case?

Comment: I want the single value of wt for that same row, where the max value of cyl was.

In other words, what was the wt of that car that the maximum number of cylinders for its group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
df2 <- (mtcars
  %>% group_by(gear,carb) 
  %>% filter(cyl==max(cyl)) 
  %>% select(cyl,mpg)
)
```

(or `select(gear,carb,cyl,mpg)` in the last line if you want to avoid a message about "Adding missing grouping variables")

This approach would be convenient if you wanted to capture several more variables and didn't want to keep typing `which.max()`.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the which.max() function works for this.

```
df1 <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear,carb) %>%
  summarise(max_cyl = max(cyl),
            mpg = mpg[which.max(cyl)])
```